# JS - Add an array of classes to an element

Tags: javascript

I decided to take off my jQuery trainer wheels and try some native JS. It's been...educational.

Anyway, here's what I'm trying to emulate:

```
$('.select_me').addClass('give_me more_classes');
```

So far, I've figured out how to select elements and add a single class to them. What I'm having trouble with, is using an array to add multiple classes to an element.

Here's what I've tried:

```
// Select the element
var div = document.querySelector('.select_me');

// Create an array with the classes to add
var classArray = ['give_me', 'more_classes'];

// Apply the new classes.
div.classList.add('just_a_test', 'okay'); // Works, but not what I want.
div.classList.add.apply(null, classArray); // Uncaught TypeError: Illegal invocation
```

I suspect I'm using `apply()` wrong, but I'm not yet knowledgeable enough to know how to use it properly. Could one of you fine folk educate me, or point me in the right direction?

JSFiddle:
https://jsfiddle.net/peg8zrw7/2/

Answer (score 15, accepted):

The context of the `.add()` method is important. Using `null` won't work because then `add` will have no idea what to operate on.

Do this instead:

```
var cl = div.classList;
cl.add.apply(cl, classArray);
// ----------^-- sets the `this` value of the `.add()` method
```

```js
// Select the element
var div = document.querySelector('.select_me');

// Create an array with the classes to add
var classArray = ['give_me', 'more_classes'];

// Apply the new classes.
var cl = div.classList;
cl.add('just_a_test', 'okay');
cl.add.apply(cl, classArray);
```

```css
div {
    width: 100px;
    height: 100px;
    background-color: #eeeeee;
}

.select_me.just_a_test.okay {
    border: 2px solid #000000;
}

.select_me.give_me {
    background: #666666;
}

.select_me.more_classes {
    border-radius: 50% 0px 50% 0px;
}
```

```html
<div class="select_me"></div>
```

---

Note that in ECMAScript 6 (and currently in Firefox) you'll be able to do this:

```
div.classList.add(...classArray);
```

Comment: Aha, that did it. Thank you very much!
And the more I hear about ES6, the better it sounds. That's one of the reasons why I left jQuery out of this particular project.

Comment: @TheRealWazzar: You're welcome. And yeah, I stopped using jQuery a couple years ago. There's just really not much need for it anymore (as long as you're not supporting IE6/7).

Comment: Worth noting: `classList` is IE10+, so you'll want to use a shim to push this back to IE8. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/classList#wrapper

Comment: quite helpful indeed!

Answer (score 0):

The best way to do more stuff in vanilla JavaScript is to always look at the [Mozilla developers](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript) site or [youmaynotneedjquery](http://youmightnotneedjquery.com)

```
if (el.classList){
  el.classList.add(className);
}else{
  el.className += ' ' + className;
}
```

This simple statement can be implemented inside a function and create your own library of code to avoid using jQuery.

Answer (score 0):

you can add `... cl` inside the parentheses, or you can directly add them like `classList.add("ClassOne","ClassTwo","ClassThree")`. [Mozilla Element.classList](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/classList)

```
// add or remove multiple classes
div.classList.add("foo", "bar", "baz");
div.classList.remove("foo", "bar", "baz");

// add or remove multiple classes using spread syntax
const cls = ["foo", "bar"];
div.classList.add(...cls);
div.classList.remove(...cls);
```